# Est-ce que « germanisme » est employé de la même façon que « anglicisme » et « gallicisme » ?

Tags: linguistique, allemand, demande-de-mot

Je suis en train d'apprendre le français et l'allemand et je suis anglophone.

Dans des cours universitaires de français que je suis, on parle souvent des *anglicismes* et comment les éviter.  La plupart des étudiants sont anglophones, donc c'est un sujet important.  On a parlé un peu de *gallicismes* aussi.  Le contexte est l'influence d'une langue sur une autre.

**Par exemple :**

- Un **anglicisme**, en français : *Je suis retard* (pour signifier « Je suis en retard »).
- Un **gallicisme**, en anglais : *I am in late* (pour signifier « *I am late* »).

Alors!

Parfois, lorsque je parle ou écris en français, l'allemand m'influence.

**Par exemple :**

*Ces idées sont **bonnes** raisonnées* (pour signifier « Ces idées sont ***bien*** raisonnées »).  En allemand, on peut utiliser le mot pour *bon* de cette façon.

---

### **Ma question : Quelle est le mot qui signifie cette erreur?**

J'ai cherché quelques réponses, mais elles ne sont pas claires pour moi.  J'ai trouvé le mot [*germanisme*](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/germanisme/36791), mais il me semble qu'il n'est pas bien défini.

Ou peut-être que je ne comprends pas bien la définition?  Également, j'apprécierais toute clarification ou explication.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Le sens *emprunt fait par le français à la langue allemande* est le sens recherché (à part que pour moi la limitation au français comme langue emprunteuse et à l'allemand comme langue source est bien trop restrictive, j'imagine volontiers qu'il y a des germanismes en russe ou en polonais et j'ai toujours entendu qualifier de germanismes les influences du néerlandais sur le français tel que parlé en Belgique, le [*TLFi*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/germanisme) a l'air d'être d'accord avec moi.)

À noter que germanisme, tout comme anglicisme d'ailleurs, désigne non seulement des tours et des mots qu'on peut considérer comme fautifs, mais aussi d'autres qui sont suffisamment passés dans l'usage pour qu'on puisse les considérer comme faisant partie du français.

Answer (score 4):

Pour confirmer ce que dit Un francophone, l'anglicisme désigne les emprunts à l'anglais dans une autre langue. Une partie de ces anglicismes sont erronés (comme *"je suis retard"), d'autres sont tout à fait acceptés et même entrés dans le dictionnaire, comme [week-end](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/week-end).

Le [calque](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calque_%28linguistique%29) syntaxique est la notion la plus proche de ce que vous souhaitez exprimer, mais cette dénomination n'est pas répandue.

Mais si vous cherchez un équivalent d'anglicisme pour l'allemand, germanisme convient. Mais l'influence de l'allemand sur la langue française étant bien plus faible que l'influence de l'anglais, je ne pense pas que "germanisme" soit compris sans explication, comme pourrait l'être "anglicisme".

Comment: Réponse qui m'a permis de découvrir qu'*ersatz* est un germanisme. C'est vrai qu'ils ne semblent pas être légion : http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Cat%C3%A9gorie:Germanismes_en_fran%C3%A7ais.

Comment: Dire qu'une expression est un calque de l'anglais/allemand est assez bien compris je pense.

Answer (score 1):

Le français romand (parlé en Suisse francophone) connaît de nombreux **germanismes**, spécialement dans les régions frontalières, comme le Jura et Neuchâtel. En Alsace aussi, pour le peu que je connais

- *Je luis crois* - ich glaube dir (datif)
- *J'attend sur toi* - ich warte auf dich (accustif)
- *Fais seulement* -  Mach nur
- *Tapis tendus*  - Spannteppich
- Un *Schluck* (une goutte)
- Une *schlaguée* ()
- Un *schnecke* - un escargot (pâtisserie, en Alsace)
- etc.